# Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell Latitude 7480 - hardware issues

Tags: 16.04, suspend, dell

Underlying single question: "how do I get my Latitude 7480's hardware to work under Ubuntu?"

The issue is chipset support, so all users see the same problems, and similar problems on different chipsets are likely unrelated. This question provides a coherent list of user-reported symptoms for kernel developers.  The answer provides a solution recipe for users and a status checklist for those thinking of getting one.  When feedback identifies a problem coherent enough for a kernel bug report, we make one and link it, but "my laptop crashes and I don't know why" is not a good kernel bug!

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS mostly works.  Issues out of the box:

1. (solved, see below) Bluetooth not recognized, other driver issues including network oddness after suspend (no wifi showing in status bar, but working), audio not working
2. (solved, see below) Samsung 960 PRO SSD not recognized in BIOS
3. (solved, see below) DualPoint Stick and 3-button row stop working after suspend or hibernate
4. (solved, see below) Virtual Terminals don't work after a while
5. TB16 dock does not work (charging and video work a little, then fail)
6. The system does not always automatically recognize new WiFi networks
7. The kernel panics, with different behavior depending on the kernel version, after some time (hours to weeks, seemingly randomly, see below)

Several solutions exist, as noted, see below.

Issue 5: If it's plugged into the dock, sometimes the video works.  Unplugging it can freeze the screen and thus hang the laptop.  It seems that after this, the kernel panics come more frequently (hours to days, even with cold reboot, see below).  I have thus done few experiments.  Nothing else on the dock works, except charging.

Issue 6: The WiFi dialog doesn't always have the networks your smartphone sees, even if they've been seen in the past.  Sometimes the WiFi won't associate.  Sometimes it disappears from ifconfig, and if that happens, you're already in Issue 7, no way to avoid it.

Issue 7: The kernel panics are strange.  In a few instances, they are true shut-off crashes, but that is rare and has only happens under the 4.10 kernel in Ubuntu 17.10.

Under the 4.8 kernel in Ubuntu 16.04.2, they happen every day or few, though a few times I've gone as long as 4 days, and once as long as a month.  That record was broken by a test of the TB16 dock, and now it's back to rebooting every day or so.

The panics are slow affairs, with messages in the logs.  The main symptom is the wifi interface disappearing.  If I hibernate and resume after that, it comes up to a blank screen with the time at the top, but you can't get a login box to type your password.

And, you have to cold boot to get the network back.  Warm boot with the power still on doesn't fix it. See the kernel bug report, below, for xinput, lspci, Xorg.0.log, etc.

System details:

```
Intel Core i7-7660U CPU
Intel HD graphics 640 with Thunderbolt 3 with Core i7 vPro
Intel 8265 wireless/BlueTooth card
Dual Pointing 82-key keyboard with smartcard, contactless smartcard, fingerprint reader, Thunderbolt 3
4-cell battery
14" QHD (2560x1440) Touchscreen w/integrated Camera, Mic
Samsung 960 PRO 2TB SSD
Crucial 2x16 GB DDR4 2133 MHz RAM
```

Comment: Yes, I did that.  See the new remarks at the top for why this is the right format for this set of issues.

Comment: Thanks for you reply even though I disagree with your stance: it would be better to deal with each dysfunctional hardware component in its own question than to lump them all together in one. You see, Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-)

Comment: As soon as we discover that several symptoms are due to one item, we break it off into a kernel bug, as was done with the touchstick.  A single firmware update took care of several of the initial items, as well.  If you can suggest another place for this, I'm all ears, but the sites that used to exist for gathering community input on getting specific laptops to work under Linux are gone.  I looked very hard and came up with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions so far:

Issue 1. Many issues were fixed when I updated to the firmware in 16.10 while still running the Linux 4.08 kernel in Ubuntu 16.04's early point releases:

```
wget -N http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.161.1_all.deb
dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.161.1_all.deb
```

Issue 2. Updated the BIOS and the firmware on the SSD, then enabled SATA ACPI and legacy boot ROMs, disable secure boot. No clue why a PCIe NVMe SSD needs a SATA option, but there it is! OK, this isn't really a Latitude issue, but it's a popular SSD, and the only way to get 2TB at the moment. I'm baffled why it uses only a legacy ROM. Maybe there's a Windows way to configure it differently. Oh well.

Issue 3. The fix is in, thanks Ben Morgan! When I suspend or hibernate and resume, the DualPoint Stick (likely ALPS under the hood, but it doesn't say that) and the three buttons above the trackpad stop working. FYI, I filed a kernel bug here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe/+bug/1694866

Issue 4. VTs work in recent kernels/firmware.

Issue 5. A Dell person told me that support for ThunderBolt 3 is coming along nicely in the new kernels. For now, video and charging work a little, then fail, but anything else does not work at all (audio, network, USB). I have tested HDMI and VGA, but not DisplayPort. Looked at closely, the native VGA quality is not as good as a $9 HDMI-to-VGA converter from VicTsing or others, though it's pretty good.

Issue 6. You have to do **Edit connections** and enter them manually (including passwords), and then it finds them.  Until it doesn't, and then you're in the slow-crash-cold-boot cycle.  This may be a clue that the crashes are related to networking.

Issue 7. With the Ubuntu 16.04.3 release, we saw the 17.10 kernel (v. 4.10) and its aforementioned fast and hard crashes.  The best thing to do as of January 2018 is to pin and run the 16.04.2 kernel and the 16.10 firmware.  Pinning the earlier HWE restored it to prior problem, a definite improvement, but still not great.  See above.

Other than that, most things seem to work:

```
Blank=untested
p=partial
m=maybe (probably need a package)
y=yes

 GPU
 smartcard
 fingerprint
 SIM card
n Thunderbolt 3 (charges, video work a little, then fail, but not USB, audio, RJ45)
p WiFi
y camera
y builtin mic
y DualPoint Stick, 3 buttons (17.04, else freeze after suspend)
y SD card (exfat filesystem is not recognized until you add packages)
y audio port 16.04 w/ 1.161.1 firmware from 16.10
y bluetooth 16.04 w/ 1.161.1 firmware from 16.10
y touchpad, 2 buttons
y HDMI
y SSD
y RJ45 (grabs cable, need tool to remove)
y CPU
y RAM 32GB (Crucial 2x16GB DDR4 2133 upgrade)
y battery
y touchscreen
y X11
y keyboard, backlight
y USB3 ports 1, 2, 3
y speakers, mic
```

Sorry for the length. I had hoped to find a single page with all these answers on it, but didn't, so I made it that way.

Comment: A single page with all the answers on it isn't really helpful as while many members may experience one of your problems the odds of someone else having all of your problems is extremely unlikely. Please review https://askubuntu.com/tour to begin.

Comment: I understand and follow the intent of that principle. These "problems" come from poor chipset support, so there is just one or a few fixes for many problems, we all have the same problems, and 1-2 packages fix them. Gathering symptoms and giving status lets developers find the problems faster, lets potential buyers know how much of this computer works today, and gives users clear instructions.  I looked hard for such a page before I bought, and wish I'd found one, so I made it.  If these problems exist on other systems, likely the fixes are different, as the problems here are in chipset code.